# Sharing AOSP output with friends

Tags: android, virtual-machine, android-source

I want to share the AOSP output with my friends. But  I don't have any idea, how to do that?

To be more clear: I've built AOSP for a device (in my case for Pixel3) and I want to share it with my friend who is also having the same phone. So what should I do now??

Also, I want to know whether the same build can be used in a Virtual Machine? If yes, please do explain how it can be done and sorry if the question is too basic (I am doing this for the first time).

Thank you for all your responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1/ To share outputed binary, you need to share all file *.img located in `<your_aosp_dir>/out/target/product/<target_name>/`

2/ Whether the same build can be used in a Virtual Machine ?

Yes. First, you need to use Android Studio to create an emulator use same API level with your AOSP. After that, you need to replace `system-qemu.img` and `vendor-qemu.img` (located in the directory described in 1/) into `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\<android-api-level>\x86_64`. Finally, you delete the old emulator then create new one with same API level. Done

Comment: Thank you so much. One more thing, is *.img enough for flashing a phone ? and can I convert it to *.iso to use in VirtualBox? Once again Thank you.